# How to get the size/length of sub-elements within an XML tag using python

Tags: python, xml.etree

I'm newbie to python and I was wondering how to get the size or number of sub elements within a parent tag lets say `participants`. The idea is to get the number of `participant` within `participants` tag.

Here is the xml:

```
<participants>
  <participant>
    <userId>James</userId>
    <role>Author</role>
  </participant>
  <participant>
    <userId>Alex</userId>
    <role>Reader</role>
  </participant>
</participants>
```

I'm using xml:

`import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET` as the module

and `ET` is assigned `dom = ET.fromstring(output)`

so far, to parse xml, I have written the following code which works:

```
for participant in dom.iter('participant'): 
    userId = participant.find('userId').text
    role = participant.find('role').text
```

But I want to get the size/length of number of `participant` in `participants` tag and this is what I'm trying to do but it doesn't give me the length:

```
print 'length', dom.findall('participants').length
```

The output I want should be:

```
length 2
```

Comment: if <participants> is root why not just do `print len(root)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> dom.findall('participant')
[<Element 'participant' at 0x10dd74090>, <Element 'participant' at 0x10dd74250>]
>>> len(dom.findall('participant'))
2
```

Comment: This also returns ***0***

Answer (score 4):

try

```
print(len(dom.findall('participant')))
```

Comment: It works, if your xml has a namespace, you have to include id.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the length:

```
root = tree.getroot()
length = len(root.findall('participant'))
print length
```